# Is there a way to make it so that swiping right opens a notification instead of dismissing it?

Tags: notifications

Is there a way to make it so that swiping right opens a notification instead of dismissing it? I come from iOS, and I'm very used to swiping to open instead of double clicking.

Comment: Changing default OS behaviour normally requires *root*. Is your device rooted ? If not unlikely there is a way

Comment: [inoty](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.notificationos10.inotify.inotyos10) gives you look and feel but didn't change notification behaviour

Comment: Ok thank you both. I can root my device it's no problem, but I'll have to find an app that will alter it though.

Comment: I searched but couldn't find any way, looks like the need isn't felt much